# Problem understanding the operations of capacitor

Tags: capacitor, amplifier, rectifier, decoupling-capacitor, coupling

So far I've learnt about some different types of capacitor arrangements , such as coupling , decoupling , bypass , filtering , and smoothing capacitor. Decoupling and bypass capacitors are the same and filtering and smoothing capacitors are the same(Correct me if I am wrong).

[image]

In this diagram of a voltage-divider bias CE amplifier above , The capacitor *C1* is used as a coupling capacitor as it is connected in series , and blocks DC signals and passes (couples) only the pure AC signal from the source to the circuitry for amplification. And , the capacitor *C2* is a bypass capacitor connected in parallel as a shunt , therefore the AC component will pass through *C2* to ground and will not be superimposed on the input as feedback , while the DC will go through the resistance *Re* ; because , We know that the capacitor reactance: $$Xc = 1/ 2\pi f C$$
Where F is the frequency of the signal and C is the capacitance. So, If the frequency increases (ac signals) the capacitive resistance decreases , and signal uninterruptedly flows from one section to another , i.e. is **coupled** , while the dc signal with zero frequency is blocked by infinite resistance. Same thing happens with the bypass capacitor *C2*

Here comes my first question , **1. Explain me why the increase of frequency decreases the reactance of capacitor? Not by using the formula written above , but using practical theory of flow of electrons , charging discharging etc.**

My second question , **2.Is the capacitor used in full wave or bridge rectifier , i.e. the filtering capacitor in coupling arrangement or decoupling arrangement or none?**

**3. What type of capacitor arrangement is it that is used on the input of a negative feedback amplifier?**

Comment: "1. Explain me why the increase of frequency decreases the reactance of capacitor?" If you can, get your hands on a function generator, and observe the voltage across a capacitor on an oscilloscope. You will understand intuitively.

Answer (score 4):

The current thru a capacitor is the *rate of change* of the voltage times the capacitance.  At the same voltage, higher frequencies have a higher rate of change (derivative), so a capacitor conducts more current at higher frequencies, all else being equal.

Another way to look at this is to imagine a capacitor driven with different frequencies, all with the same peak to peak voltage.  That peak to peak voltage dictates how much charge is sloshed around each ½ cycle.  The higher frequencies will cause the same charge to be sloshed more often.  Charge moving per time is current, so the higher frequency voltages cause a higher current thru the capacitor.

Don't get so hung up on names of how a capacitor is used in a circuit.  Not all uses have short names, so don't try to force one onto every occasion.  Generally *bypass capacitor* is used for the relatively small and high frequency cap close the the point of use of power.  It's job is to be a short term but immediately responsive reservoir to keep the voltage smooth as the current demand changes quickly.

You can call C1 a *DC blocking* cap.  I wouldn't try to put a particular name on the use of C2.

Comment: +1 for the 'sloshing more often' analogy